# How to solve send mail: ORA-29279 SMTP issue

Tags: sql, database, oracle, smtp

I'm getting an ORA-29279 error when running the below snipped. Suggest me if some issue in this

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CPO.fsc_temp_MAIL (l_from  IN VARCHAR2,
               l_to    IN VARCHAR2,
               Subject IN VARCHAR2,
               Mesg    IN VARCHAR2,
               Cc      IN VARCHAR2 default null,
               P_Html  BOOLEAN := FALSE) IS
  l_to1       VARCHAR2(32000) := l_to;
  Mhost  VARCHAR2(64) := '192.168.0.6';
  crlf        varchar2(2) := CHR(13) || CHR(10);
  conn UTL_SMTP.connection;
  Address   varchar2(32700);
BEGIN
  conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(Mhost,25);
     UTL_SMTP.helo(conn, Mhost);
 UTL_SMTP.mail(conn, l_from);
  GET_TEMP_INFO_MAIL(conn,l_to1);
  If Cc is not null then
    GET_TEMP_INFO_MAIL(conn,Cc);
  end if;
  IF P_Html THEN
   Address := 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD MON RRRR HH24:MI:SS') ||
   crlf ||'From: ' || l_from ||
   crlf ||'To: ' || l_to ||
   crlf ||'Cc: ' || Cc ||
   crlf ||'Subject: ' || Subject || crlf

      || 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii' || crlf
      || 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' || crlf
      || '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">' || crlf
      || '<html>'  || crlf
      || '<head>'  || crlf
      || '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">' || crlf
      || '<title>' || subject || '</title>' || crlf
      || '</head>' || crlf
      || '<body>'  || crlf|| utl_tcp.crlf
      || mesg || crlf
      || '</body></html>';
  ELSE
   Address := 'Date: ' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD MON RRRR HH24:MI:SS') ||
   crlf ||'From: ' || l_from ||
   crlf ||'To: ' || l_to ||
   crlf ||'Cc: ' || Cc ||
   crlf ||'Subject: ' || Subject ||
   crlf || utl_tcp.crlf || mesg;
  END IF;
  UTL_SMTP.data(conn, Address);
  UTL_SMTP.quit(conn);
  EXCEPTION
 WHEN utl_smtp.Transient_Error OR utl_smtp.Permanent_Error then
   raise_application_error(-20000, 'Unable to send mail: '||sqlerrm);

END;
```

when I execute that procedure

```
execute fsc_temp_MAIL('usmanafb@ctm.com.pk','abc@ctm.com.pk','test for subject  ','sdf','xyz@ctm.com.pk',True);
```

> ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

[image]

don't know how to deal with this
this is some kind of smtp setting ? **all email address is valid**

if some one have better solution then tell me I create these pocedure in plsql

Comment: Is has nothing to do with the email address you are sending to.  Your SMTP server requires authentication.  Read the [documenation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_smtp.htm#BHAGEECF)

Comment: execute testing_email('usmanafb@ctm.com.pk','mshakeel@ctm.com.pk','mshakeel@ctm.com.pk','Testing subject','testing msg',message_status)  can u tell me what is message status and which value i pass for message status

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with message status.  Your email server is requesting a username/password in order for the client to login to it.  Your example code does not provide that, and that is why you are getting the error.  Please read the doc link I posted.

Comment: I read your provided link and I am talking about the that procedure which is in that link

Answer (score 2):

The result code from the SMTP server: 530 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated is telling you that you need to authenticate with the server.  Specifically result code 530 indicates that you "must issue a STARTTLS command. Encryption required for requested authentication mechanism"

The `STARTTLS` command further requires you to use an extended form of the call to `OPEN_CONNECTION` passing in details of the Oracle wallet to use when securing the connection.  You may also need to make a call the `AUTH` function or procedure to fully authenticate your connection.

Please view the [UTL_SMTP](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_smtp.htm) documentation for additional info.

Comment: i used oracle 11 g database i think which not compatible with my code am i right ?

Comment: Support for SSL/TLS secured connections was added in Oracle 11g, or at least the info on is in the [11g docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS71479)

Answer (score 0):

Check your host. This is the host problem.
Use the query.

SELECT UTL_INADDR.get_host_name,UTL_INADDR.get_host_address('your-server-address') FROM dual;